# How to transitively set "CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS" via an imported target?

Tags: c++, cmake, luajit

I'm implementing a FindXXX.cmake for a library, that requires the exe that links with it, to add specific linker flags.

Specifically this is for LuaJIT which requires the app be linked using:

```
-pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000
```

I'd rather not just set CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS, because there may be other exes that don't link to LuaJIT that I'm building in my project and would much rather this come from a transitive setting.

Also, I can't just add this to IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES because those flags get used on other libraries that link against this dependency, and the setting is specific to linking an application.

Extra credit: This should only apply to 64-bit mac osx builds.

Comment: `... the setting is specific to linking an application.`- When talk about propagation of the properties via linking, CMake **doesn't distinguish libraries and applications**. So, every propagated property will be assigned both for the application and libraries. May be, there is a property which affects on an executable but not on a library. But I am unaware about such.

Comment: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS does that. But it's not a target based setting.

Comment: Yes, I know that `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` is applicable only for applications and not for libraries. But this is not a property but a *global variable*, so it cannot be propagated via linking. Unlike many other variable-settings, this variable has no corresponded property - it is used by CMake only as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `target_link_libraries(your_target your_flags)`. Your flags will have to start with `-`.  You can check for Apple systems with the `APPLE` variable, and you can check for 64-bit by using `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P`.

You can just all that together in an if statement like so:

```
if(APPLE AND CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    target_link_libraries(your_target your_flags)
endif()
```

Comment: Do you mean my executable for the "your_target"? Because the question is how I can apply this transitively from a library to the executable that links to the library.

Comment: I've tried what you described but with `IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES` instead of `link_flags` and when non-exe targets link to it, I get: "ld: -pagezero_size option can only be used when linking a main executable". And I tried "LINK_FLAGS" and "link_flags" (for this imported target) like in your answer, but neither produced the linker flag in the exe OR libraries with that depdendency at all.

Comment: @johnb003 I edited it. I was reading the docs, and I was led astray. That's totally my fault. If that doesn't work, I'll see if I can find another solution